# Convert uploaded .csv to memorystream and then to c# datatable in .Net Core

Tags: c#, csv, memorystream, .net-standard-2.0, iformfile

I am trying to make an application that will take in multiple file types and convert them to a c# `DataTable`. To do this I am first copying the file to a `MemoryStream` and recording the file's extension.  Then based on the extension I need to read the stream in different ways.

I'm having difficulty when it comes to uploading a `.csv` file.  I first copy it to a memory stream but then I am not being able to read from it correctly.  Please help.

**Example Code**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file) {
    Datatable dt = new DataTable();
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

    if (file.length > 0) {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
            dt = ConvertFileToDataTable(ms, extension);
        }
    }
}

public DataTable ConvertFileToDataTable(MemoryStream stream, string ext) {
    switch (ext.ToLower()) {
        case ".xlsx":
            // Already have this working
            break;
        case ".csv":
            // This is where I need help
    }
}
```

With the CSV I am making the assumption that the first row contains the headers.  If I could just convert the `MemoryStream` back into a csv string then I could handle the logic from there, I just don't know how to do that part.

The reason I need to do the conversion to a `MemoryStream` is because I'm working on a .Net Standard Library that wouldn't have access to IFormFile.  It would take in the stream and return a data table.  Basically, it handles the code in the method `ConvertFileToDataTable` above.

Comment: Have you tried: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());`

Comment: @RyanWilson That worked.  Please enter that as an answer so that I can mark it correct.

Comment: Added as you requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the byte array as a string by using:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```